# Android Does not show map

Tags: android, android-maps

I am developing application for getting current location. I'm using com.google.android.maps library and also generate the API key for accessing the Google Maps.
But it only show the blank Google Map when I launch the app in the emulator. I'm also passing the longitude and latitude from DDMS.
Anyone can give me suggestion for what can I do?

Comment: Check whether you are running on Google API emulator..

Comment: When you hit Built and Run on eclipse it uses default.keystore for the application.Possibly you are using default or some other keystore for your application and have registered different keystore for map apiKeys.Check it at Window > Android > Build > Custom Debug Keystore

Answer (score 1):

Add the the below permissions in Android manifest.xml file ,before/after the application tag.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

If the map does not show up after adding permissions,then the problem is in api key itself.Generate another one and make sure the MD5 must be a copy and paste.